# CakePHP 2.1 - Saving (and creating) multiple Join Models and associated models

Tags: cakephp

My model relationship is as follows:

```
Student hasMany ClassStudent
Class hasMany ClassStudent
ClassStudent belongsTo Student
ClassStudent belongsTo Class
ClassStudent is a join model.
```

What I want to do is create Student(s), use an existing Class or create a new one, and create a join model record that links the Students and classes.

I want to do this all in one call to save (if this is even possible).

I have tried:

```
$data = array(
    'Student' => array(
        '0' => array( ... ), // Data in here
        '1' => array( ... ),
        ...,
        'n' => array( ... )
    ),
    'Class' => array(
        'class_id' => x // The class that I want the above students to be associated with
    )
)
```

What I want to do is create n records of students and also add them to a class (possibly creating a class at the same time if the users wants to add a new one).  I also want to create a join model record for each Student to the Class when I am creating the Student records.

Is this possible?  I am using Cake 2.1.0 (today's stable release), and I have tried the different types of saveAll (saveAssociated and saveMany) with $options['deep'] = true.

Is it possible my data array is not in the correct format?

**EDIT:**
I have also tried:

```
$data = array(
    'ClassStudent' => array(
        '0' => array(
            'Student' => array (...), // Data
            'Class' => array(id => x) // The id of the Class the Student should be associated to
        ...,
        'n' => array(
            'Student' => array(...), // n-th Student
            'Class' => array(id => x)
     )
 );

$this->saveAll($data['ClassStudent'], array('deep' => true));
```

In the above case, it successfully creates new Student records in the students table, but nothing is created in the join table.

Answer (score -1):

saveAll (saveAll is a wrapper to saveMany and saveAssociated) is the right tool for the job. Take a look at the documentation for [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-hasmany-through-data), I don't see any notes about it changing for 2.1. Having taking more time to read, here are some thoughts

First off, is there a type in your array structure. You have

```php
'Class' => array ( 'class_id' => x )
```

If the Class is already defined and you are just wanting to add a student, then it would be

```php
'ClassStudent' => array( 'class_id' => x )
```

With that said, CakesPHP ORM should allow you to use a saveAll with on a hasMany using a numerical index, so if assuming you have a typo, there follow might work for you

```php
$data = array(
    'Student' => array(
        '0' => array( ... ), // Data in here
        '1' => array( ... ),
        ...,
        'n' => array( ... )
     ),
    'ClassStudent' => array(
        'class_id' => x // The class that I want the above students to be associated with
    )
)
$this->ClassStudent->saveAll($data);
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for the reply.  I did use that method you linked to save one join model at a time and it worked.  But in that case I was only doing one.

So it is not possible to create multiple join models at once?

Comment: This is actually more interesting then it looks. After some more reading, it seems that the Cake documentation might be causing some confusion. As of right now, it seems you can only save one set of association at time, call the saveAll on the ClassStudent model

Comment: Hey Ryan, I have tried the above data format and it does not seem to work.  As for my call to save, not sure if it matters, but in my ClassStudent model, I have the function that calls $this->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true)) (I have tried it with and without deep).  And then in my Class Controller, I am calling the method as $this->Class->ClassStudent->saveClassStudents($this->request->data).

Note that when I check the database there are no new records.

Comment: I edited my original post to show what other data array structures I tried.